# Read TLS enable emails using IMAP library in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, smtplib, imaplib

I am getting  below error while read mail using python script. I am using outlook as email server.
The same code is working for my personal email but not for may company email address.
I verified that tow-factor authentication is not enabled

- **Mail_read.py**

```
import imaplib
import email
import ssl
from getpass import getpass
import html2text


imap_server="outlook.office365.com"


email_addrss="name@companyname.com"
password =  getpass() 

# Login to Outlook email
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_server,port=993)


imap.login(email_addrss,password)

            
imap.close()
```

- **Error**

```
    imap.login(email_addrss,password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/imaplib.py", line 612, in login
    raise self.error(dat[-1])
imaplib.IMAP4.error: b'LOGIN failed.'
```

- Also, I verify that using SMTP protocol I can able to sent mail.
- **sent_mail_smtp.py (Working)**

  ```
  import smtplib


  mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com',587)
  mailserver.ehlo()
  mailserver.starttls()
  mailserver.login('name@companyname.com', 'Password')


  mailserver.sendmail("dname@companyname.com","receiver email","email body")
  mailserver.quit()
  ```
- I verify that there are email and password is correct
- It's working for SMTP library

Please help me to solve this issue

Thanks

Comment: Microsoft no longer allows basic logins with Office365. You need to use Modern Authentication/OAUTH2 to log into Office365 mail servers

Comment: Basic login with email and password is working for me on my personal email.

But it's not working (Read email) for my organisation/company email. Two factor auth is also disabled

I can able to send email using same organisation/company email.

Comment: Your personal account (outlook) and a business account (office365) have different rules, but does not change the fact that basic login is no longer allowed for Office365: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online